# Array of Class's Objects and accessing in foreach loop

Tags: java, class, foreach

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class A{
int age;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    A[] a=new A[4];
    System.out.println("Enter the elements:");

    for(A i:a){
        i.age=s.nextInt();
    }
}
}
```

In this code I want user to give input but it is generating

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at A.main(a.java:10)
```

Please guide me with this error.

Answer (score 2):

You've initialized the array but have forgotten to initialize it's elements as well.

```
A[] a=new A[4];

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = new A(); 
}
```

Note that just doing `new A[4];` creates the array but the individual `A` object references (`a[0]`, `a[1]` etc.) are initialized to `null` only.

---

If you're having trouble visualizing why is it so, the following should help.

```
A[] a = null;

// NO array object
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

a = new A[4];

// Array object with NO elements
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = new A(); 
}

// Array object with A() elements
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

***Output :***

```
null
[null, null, null, null]
[A@15db9742, A@6d06d69c, A@7852e922, A@4e25154f]
```